# Mailchimp Forms - Is there a way to use "&" in a name field

Tags: html, mailchimp

I am putting together a Mailchimp contact form to have people sign in through a kiosk machine.

The issue that I am having is when I have a couple signing in - usually with a "&" between the first names

Example: John & Mary Smith

When they enter in that format, this message appears:

Please be sure that name fields use alphanumeric characters, commas, dashes, single quotes and periods only

The snippet of HTML code is this

```
<td align="right" class="formLabel">First Name:
    <input type="text" name="MERGE1" id="MERGE1" size="25" value="*|MERGE1|*">
    <div class="error">*|HTML:FNAMEERROR|*</div>
</td>`
```

I was wondering if there was a way to allow for the use of the "&" sign in the name field?

I tried looking at the field settings within Mailchimp, but I can't seem to find anyway to add an exception